# AOSP Building error with Ubuntu Beaver 18.02

Tags: android, build, android-source, failed-installation

Good morning

Could you helpme when i need to build ( Make -j1) I get follow error:

```
============================================
[W][2021-07-21T08:13:39+0200][9522] void cmdline::logParams(nsjconf_t *)():250 Process will be UID/EUID=0 in the global user namespace, and will have user root-level access to files
[W][2021-07-21T08:13:39+0200][9522] void cmdline::logParams(nsjconf_t *)():260 Process will be GID/EGID=0 in the global user namespace, and will have group root-level access to files
[100% 44/44] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
cd "$(dirname "out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i "$BUILDER"     --top "$TOP"     --out "out/soong"     -n "out"     -d "out/soong/build.ninja.d"     -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -globFile out/soong/.bootstrap/build-globs.ninja -o out/soong/build.ninja --available_env out/soong/soong.environment.available --used_env out/soong/soong.environment.used Android.bp
Killed
08:31:29 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

#### failed to build some targets (17:54 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: When it just says "Killed", usually the process that was building got killed by the OS for some reason ( usually low on memory). I'd suggest you run dmesg on your laptop and check what it says after you get this failure

Comment: Were you able to repeat the generated error message more than once?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rick and Johnh it seems that is insuffient memory  Output dmesg --->'''
[95217.126424] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/,task=soong_build,pid=26458,uid=0
[95217.126496] Out of memory: Killed process 26458 (soong_build) total-vm:12686920kB, anon-rss:10960824kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:23436kB oom_score_adj:0
[95218.108537] oom_reaper: reaped process 26458 (soong_build), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[141870.366653] kauditd_printk_skb: 86 callbacks suppressed
'''

Comment: is there any suggestion or solution to run into VM Ubuntu Beaver 18.02 x64 , 11GB RAM, 350 GB ?

Comment: Solved: I have to increase my CPU cores and 64GB memory